# LaTex: Table is spilling over page on right

Tags: latex, margin, longtable

How can I fix a `longtable` to not spill over on the right? With `table` I use `\scalebox{0.9}`, but `scalebox` does not seem to work with `longtable`.

```
\begin{longtable}{cccccccccc}

\caption{This is a caption}\\

TABLE TABLE TABLE

\end{longtable}
```

My table has ten columns and therefore the margins are not even on both sides. Does anyone know how to center the table so the left and right margins are equal?

Comment: I don't know for sure if this will work, but have you tried wrapping the whole thing in `\begin{minipage}{<desired width>}` ... `\end{minipage}`?

Comment: it compiles, but does not seem to effect the table (tried 2in-12in) \begin{minipage}{2in}

Answer (score 1):

figure out which columns are giving you the most problems, then change `\begin{longtable}{cccccccccc}` to `\begin{longtable}{>{\raggedright}p{width-of-column}ccccccccc}`

the `>{\raggedright}` will tell latex to make the cell content with ragged right edges instead of justified

and

the `p{width-of-column}` will allow you to specify the width of your column.

Comment: And I can use it to replace in `\begin{longtable}[c]{|l|l|l|l|l|}` ?